# How to increase cache expiration time for pages in Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

How to increase the cache expiration time for particular pages in Magento 2?

Comment: Please don't use specific-version tags unless you know that your question is specifically *and* exclusively about that version.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for updating. Any idea on my query?

Comment: See this Q&A on the Magento Stack Exchange site: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/300373/how-to-set-page-cache-expires-to-7-days -- your questions may be better received there, instead... there are far more users looking at Magento questions there than here, at least.

Comment: Thanks, @TylerH but I have a few different requirements i.e. I have multiple paths like https://js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-1210.min.js, https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js & for each I want to set a different value of caching. I am not getting any idea of how to do the same. Can you please guide me on this part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache time-to-live (TTL) for your media and static files is set in the .magento.app.yaml configuration file using the expires key.

Please follow below link to do that
[set cache expiration time](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/set-cache.html)